# Chakra UI + React Hook Form error wrong Types

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hook-form, chakra-ui

I am trying to use ChakraUI and React-Hook-Form to create my form in TypeScript. However, my **errors** are giving me problems related to typescript it seems. I copy pasted this code from chakra ui/react-hook-form template provided on chakra's website. Here is the code:

```
import {
  Box,
  Heading,
  FormErrorMessage,
  FormLabel,
  FormControl,
  Input,
  Button,
  Text,
  FormHelperText,
} from '@chakra-ui/react'
import React from 'react'
import styles from '../../theme/styles'
import textStyles from '../../theme/text-styles'
import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form'

const DescribeCargo = () => {
  const {
    handleSubmit,
    register,
    formState: { errors, isSubmitting },
  } = useForm()

  function onSubmit(values: any) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(values, null, 2))
        resolve(values)
      }, 3000)
    })
  }

  return (
    <>
      <Box {...styles.bodyContainer}>
        <Heading {...textStyles.componentHeader} my={7} as='h3'>
          Describe the cargo
        </Heading>
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
          <FormControl isInvalid={errors.name}>
            <FormLabel htmlFor='name'>First name</FormLabel>
            <Input
              id='name'
              placeholder='name'
              {...register('name', {
                required: 'This is required',
                minLength: { value: 4, message: 'Minimum length should be 4' },
              })}
            />
            <FormErrorMessage>{errors.name && errors.name.message}</FormErrorMessage>
          </FormControl>
          <FormControl isInvalid={errors.lastname}>
            <FormLabel htmlFor='lastname'>Last name</FormLabel>
            <Input
              id='lastname'
              placeholder='lastname'
              {...register('lastname', {
                required: 'This is required',
                minLength: { value: 8, message: 'Minimum length should be 8' },
              })}
            />
            <FormErrorMessage>{errors.lastname && errors.lastname.message}</FormErrorMessage>
          </FormControl>
          <Button mt={4} colorScheme='teal' isLoading={isSubmitting} type='submit'>
            Submit
          </Button>
        </form>
      </Box>
    </>
  )
}

export default DescribeCargo
```

**Here are the errors I'm getting:**

```
TS2322: Type 'Merge<FieldError, FieldErrorsImpl<DeepRequired<any>>> | undefined' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'.
  Type 'Merge<FieldError, FieldErrorsImpl<DeepRequired<any>>>' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'.
    Type 'Merge<FieldError, FieldErrorsImpl<DeepRequired<any>>>' is missing the following properties from type 'ReactPortal': key, children, type, props
    48 |               })}
    49 |             />
  > 50 |             <FormErrorMessage>{errors.name && errors.name.message}</FormErrorMessage>
       |                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    51 |           </FormControl>
    52 |           <FormControl isInvalid={errors.lastname}>
    53 |             <FormLabel htmlFor='lastname'>Last name</FormLabel>
```

```
TS2322: Type 'Merge<FieldError, FieldErrorsImpl<DeepRequired<any>>> | undefined' is not assignable to type 'boolean | undefined'.
  Type 'Merge<FieldError, FieldErrorsImpl<DeepRequired<any>>>' is not assignable to type 'boolean | undefined'.
    38 |         </Heading>
    39 |         <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
  > 40 |           <FormControl isInvalid={errors.name}>
       |                        ^^^^^^^^^
    41 |             <FormLabel htmlFor='name'>First name</FormLabel>
    42 |             <Input
    43 |               id='name'
```

Perhaps I could write it without Chakra - however I would like to stick with the theme of this app. I changed the type of errors to any, however it's not helping much.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I had the exact same type issue. I solved this with :

```
<FormErrorMessage>
    {errors.title && errors.title.message?.toString()}
</FormErrorMessage>
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't know about chakra UI, but issue is because type of `errors` from `useForm` hook and `children` type of `FormErrorMessage` are different. For first error, try updating like this

```
<FormErrorMessage>
    <Text>{errors.name && errors.name.message}</Text>
</FormErrorMessage>
```

For 2nd error `isInvalid` prop expects either `boolean` or `undefined`. So, you have to convert `errors.name` to `boolean`

```
<FormControl isInvalid={Boolean(errors.name)}>
```

If there is some error in name field, then `errors.name` will not be empty and `Boolean(errors.name)` is true

Answer (score 2):

### What's going wrong

The reason you are getting a TypeError when you use `errors.name.message` is:

```
Type 'string | FieldError | Merge<FieldError, FieldErrorsImpl<any>> | undefined' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'.
  Type 'FieldError' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'.
    Type 'FieldError' is missing the following properties from type 'ReactPortal': key, children, props
```

The `FieldError` type from react-hook-form doesn't work as a ReactNode which is what Chakra expects.

However in your case I'm assuming you are interested in `errors.name.message` only if it is a string.

### Fixing it with a simple typeguard

You can use a typeguard:

```
const nameError =
    typeof errors?.name?.message === 'string' ? errors?.name?.message : undefined;
```

### A reusable typeguard

However since you have a few different inputs, it might be easier to define a function that you can reuse:

```
 const getErrorMessage = (fieldName: string, errs: Record<string, any>): string | undefined =>
    typeof errs?.[fieldName]?.message === 'string' ? errs?.[fieldName]?.message : undefined;

  const nameError = getErrorMessage('name', errors);
```

Which you can then use like this:

```
 <FormControl isInvalid={!!nameError}>
     <FormLabel htmlFor="name">First name</FormLabel>
       <Input
          id="name"
          placeholder="name"
           {...register('name', {
            required: 'This is required',
            minLength: { value: 4, message: 'Minimum length should be 4' }
            })}
            />
     <FormErrorMessage>{getErrorMessage('name', errors)} </FormErrorMessage>
</FormControl>
```

### An input component to make your life easier

As an alternative, you can make your own component to handle these types of inputs:

import {
useForm,
FieldErrors,
FieldValues,
UseFormRegister,
RegisterOptions
} from 'react-hook-form';

```
const CustomInputWithErrorComponent = ({
  fieldName,
  errors,
  placeholderText,
  register,
  label,
  options
}: {
  fieldName: string;
  errors: FieldErrors<FieldValues>;
  placeholderText?: string;
  register: UseFormRegister<FieldValues>;
  label: string;
  options: RegisterOptions;
}) => {
  const errorMessage =
    typeof errors?.name?.message === 'string' ? errors?.name?.message : undefined;
  return (
    <FormControl isInvalid={!!errorMessage}>
      <FormLabel htmlFor={fieldName}>{label}</FormLabel>
      <Input id={fieldName} placeholder={placeholderText} {...register(fieldName, options)} />
      <FormErrorMessage>{errorMessage}</FormErrorMessage>
    </FormControl>
  );
};
```

### Abstract (almost) everything

Depending on your project, you can even leverage `useFormContext` so you don't need to pass `register` or `errors`.

Inside your `CustomInputWithErrors` component you can just do:

```
const {formState: {errors}, register } = useFormContext();
```

This however requires you to wrap your form like so:

```
const methods = useForm()
      
<FormProvider {...methods}> 

// inputs and the rest of your form here
```

Comment: Great answer, i love the composability

Answer (score 1):

Create an interface outisde the component

```
interface IFormInputs {
  name: string;
  lastname: string;
}
```

then assign the interface to `useForm` hook

```
const {
    register,
    formState: { errors },
    handleSubmit,
  } = useForm<IFormInputs>();
```

This should solve the problem.